# Test view correctly rendered in Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

How do I do the following in RSpec?

```
test "should get home" do
  get :home
  assert_response :success
  get :home, { mobile: 1 }
  assert_response :success
end
```

Note that my mobile views have a different mime-type  (i.e.  .mobile.erb )

Failed attempt:

```
render_views
describe "GET home" do
    it "renders the index view" do
      get :home
      expect(response).to render_template("home")
      get :home, { mobile: 1 }
      expect(response).to render_template("home")
    end
  end
```

This test doesn't fail if I break the mobile view.

Comment: Hey, what exactly is the error message? Also, does the test pass if you place `render_views` inside the `describe` block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check that the request was successful you can use:

```
it { is_expected.to respond_with 200 }
```

As the best practice is to have [single expectation](http://betterspecs.org/#single) per test, I would refactor your example to something like this:

```
describe "GET home" do
  render_views

  context 'with regular view' do
    before do
      get :home
    end

    it { is_expected.to respond_with 200 }
    it "renders the index view" do
      expect(page).to have_content 'some header'
    end
  end

  context 'with mobile view' do
    before do
      get :home, { mobile: 1 }
    end

     it { is_expected.to respond_with 200 }
     it "renders the index view" do
       expect(page).to have_content 'some header'
     end
  end
end
```

That's just an idea for you to start.

Comment: I've seen this before in RSpec - it seems off that the test needs to include some filler content code. If I totally change the content in the view, the test will start the fail.

Comment: @WillTaylor can you provide an example where you check that the template was rendered properly? I'm not saying code above is perfect. Each particular situation should have specific approach.

Comment: I'm getting this error too: undefined local variable or method `page'

Comment: Example of working version: just using the normal "rails test" framework, the   "assert_response :success" fails if it can't render the view. RSpec doesn't render views by default, so I was getting stuck! Thanks for your help by the way!

Comment: It looks like the "page" bit is because I need to add capybara

Comment: @WillTaylor Ok, good that it helps and sorry if I was sound rude in my comment.

Comment: No didn't sound rude at all! Really appreciate all of the help

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
expect(response).to be_success
```

Comment: Doesn't fail correctly.  Adding to my view "<%= Booking.find(213) %>
" (where there is no booking 213), this doesn't work in the browser, but the test passes.